# Carrierwave image resizing not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

I cannot get the image resizer that I put in my rails app to work properly.  I added a resizer to `picture_uploader.rb` but it's not working correctly:

**uploader/picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

And here is the uploader:

**home.html.erb**

```
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
```

I need the images to upload at the same sizes.

Comment: Are you uploading images smaller than 400x400?

Comment: That was the problem.  I was using screenshot crops from google images that were below 400x400.  Used pics from my iphone and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize_to_limit gets in action only if image size if larger than specified. Read docs here: [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick:resize_to_limit)

You would be better off using [resize_to_fil](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/RMagick:resize_to_fill)

Comment: Perfect. Was wondering how to bring images up to the specified dimensions